# USB HID empty feature reports

Tags: c, usb-hid

I am communicating with a USB HID device using C in Windows.

Per the USB device's documentation, I am sending/receiving feature reports (Report ID 0x03) over the Control Pipe.

I can successfully send and receive feature reports, but in many cases when I do a get feature report, instead of receiving the report I expect back from the device it will send an empty report: a report with the correct Report ID of 0x03 as the first byte, but then all the remaining bytes are zeroes.

I am sure that this is not a misread in my code, as I can also see these "empty" reports when I use a USB sniffer/analyzer.

I am not familiar with USB HID: is this normal? Should I just ignore these "empty" reports?

Thanks.

Comment: 0 sometimes means "use whatever i sent last time." Are you requesting the same report multiple times?

Comment: I am sometimes, but it almost seems like zero reports are being sent randomly. I send a report, then am expecting more or "new" data, but then these kinds of reports come back and it's causing issues.